# dnn fck editor source code

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I need dotnetnuke fck editor's source code. Can you please give me directions for editing the fck editors source?

I need to add images to portal root folder externally.after uploading image it cannot select from the image manager. Image manager only show files uploaded from image manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working:
the dnn source editor image gallery is working from the database.ie.if you manually copy a file into the portal folder it does not visible in the fck editor gallery.the file listing is done from the databese.

so the solution is,you should make a uploader section for uploading images and give an entry in nuke's file table.then it will visible in gallery.

Answer (score 3):

FCKeditor provider is not a part of the DNN source package anymore, but you can find it at:

http://dnnfckeditor.codeplex.com

Image gallery checks that the portal has read permissions to the folder, and filters the files by extension, allowing only image files. But you should see all the image files, regardless if they show up in the DNN file manager.

But still, I would check if the files are visible in the DNN file manager, and if not, run "Synchronize Files" from the root level.

Comment: There is also a schedule item to sync files on a schedule - usually if you are adding files in a method other than the DNN methods you need this turned on.

Answer (score 1):

There's a source package for the editor provider at http://dnnfckeditor.codeplex.com/